# Populate dropdown with array items via search bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, arrays, searchbar

I'm having trouble populating a dropdownlist with listItems from an Array.  I'm creating a search bar to search through items that I've retrieved from a database that I stored in an array.  I gave it a shot, and below is what I've come up with.

Nothing happens when the button is clicked.  No exceptions or errors.

Thanks in advance!

```
public partial class Client_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  List<string> clients = new List<string>();
  List<string> id = new List<string>();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=EDITOR1;Initial Catalog=info;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name from Client", cnn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Client");

        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select clientId from Client", cnn);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds2, "Client");

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Client"].Rows)
        {
            clients.Add(row["name"].ToString());
        }
        foreach (DataRow row in ds2.Tables["Client"].Rows)
        {
            clients.Add(row["clientId"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = 0; x > (clients.Count()-1); x++)
    {
        if (clients[x].StartsWith(TextBox1.Text))
        {
            ListItem a = new ListItem(clients[x], id[x]);
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(a);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Are the results not displaying? Are you getting an exception? Please be more specific what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update it now, but the results aren't populating. No exceptions though.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint in the code and ran through step by step to see if the foreach loops are traversing the data in the Client table?

Comment: for (int x = 0; x > (clients.Count()-1); x++) should be for (int x = 0; x < clients.Count(); x++)

Comment: You could change select name from Client to select name, clientId  from Client and use one foreach to add them both at the same time

Comment: Thanks kevchadders, and andyw_! It now works! I'm a little embarrassed to say I've been struggling on this for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem I see is your loop

`for (int x = 0; x > (clients.Count()-1); x++)`

should be

`for (int x = 0; x < clients.Count(); x++)`

Further,

You shouldn't need to query the database twice and iterate through the result twice.